# How can we retain the selected item in li of ui tag on post back in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have created a list of items as a slider by using repeater tag and the list contains at least 100 items. When I select the 21st item of li or click on 21st image button in li the click event is performed. But the selected Button is not retained on post back and items listed from first item. My html code is given below

```
<ul>
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="view1">
           <div class="item-container1">
              <div class="image">
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="Imgbtncnl" runat="server" 
                    Style='height: 75px; width: 75px'
                    ImageUrl='<%#Eval("CHANNELIMAGEURL") %>' 
                    title='<%# Eval("CHANNELNAME") %>' 
                    OnClick="Imgbtncnl_Click" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CHANNELNAME") %>' />
               </div>
               <div class="text">
                  <div class="title"><%# Eval("CHANNELNAME") %></div>
                  <div class="description"><%# Eval("Description") %></div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Pageload function :

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (Session["EmailID"] != null && Request.QueryString["chid"] != null)
    {
        chname = Request.QueryString["chid"].ToString();
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            drpCategoryBind();
            dbcon.strCommand = "Select * from AddPrograms";
            DataTable dt = dbcon.selecttable();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rptImages.DataSource = dt;
                rptImages.DataBind();
            }
            videoload();
            BindUsername();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("UserLogin.aspx?chid='Al-Afasy'");
    }
  }
```

onclick event :

```
 protected void Imgbtncnl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
     {
         dbcon.strCommand = "Select  ARABCHANNELID, LIVEURL_NY, CHANNELNAME,CHANNELIMAGEURL from AddPrograms where CHANNELNAME='" + Session["datachname"].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = dbcon.dataread();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                chanUrl = dr["LIVEURL_NY"].ToString();
                chanName = dr["CHANNELNAME"].ToString();

            }
        }
        if (chanUrl == null)
        {
            inpHide = "Programs/colorbars.flv";
            inpcname = "Arabic Channel";
        }
        else
        {
            inpcname = chanName.ToString();
            inpHide = chanUrl.ToString();
        }
        jwplayer(inpHide, inpcname);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add onclick event function

Comment: Are you binding the repeater in Page_Load? Can you post your code for Page_Load and databind?